# How to deactivate a service under an IIS host

Tags: wcf, iis

I have more WCF services under an IIS virtual directory. I have to deactivate some of them and I thought, I have just commet out the appropriate sections in the web.config, but it seems not, the client works. Just in the browser comes the error message, that the metadata is not reachable.

Is it actually possible to somehow deactivate the services?

I had an another idea, to rename the .svc files, but I want to avoid that solution.

I am using .Net 4.0.

---

I've found that:

Simplified Configuration for WCF Services:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one service in the Web application, you may simply stop the app pool associated with the service, provided you have one app pool per web application.

If you have more than one services in the application and you just want to deactivate one,you may remove the respective svc file; or if you use config activation without any svc file, you may comment out respective line in the config. For more details about how to activate services without SVC files, you may read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World and check the source codes attached in the article.

Comment: I have more .svc files